# What is a word that means "uncontemplated"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I have been trying to describe when people say or do something or hold an opinion where it seems like they haven't spent much or almost any time thinking deeply about it, thinking it through, turning it over in their mind, looking at it from different angles, debating different aspects, analysing possible contradictions, considering if everything adds up, deepening their justification for their stance, etc.

I feel like there is a word out there for it but I can't think of it.

It's not "thoughtless" because this has a too general implication of "you are stupid", but I want to emphasise very precisely, "you didn't contemplate, you didn't think about it actively and rigorously".

I can only think of "uncontemplated", "unconsidered" or "unanalysed" at the moment and it sounds a bit awkward and it's not in common usage. I don't like "undeveloped" because it sounds haughty and presumptuous in a way I don't mean, sort of like "Oh, if only you knew the true theory like I do, once you get to my level, etc." "Rash" is roughly the idea but it focuses too much on sort of emotionally impulsive actions, so I wouldn't use it.

Comment: Not a single word. "Not thought through". https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/thought+through

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions:

- [ill-thought-out](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ill-thought-out)

> Not considered carefully enough

- [unnreasoned](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unreasoned)

> not founded on reason or reasoning

Answer (score 1):

> **superficial** adjective (NOT DEEP)
>
> If something written or said is superficial, it does not show any real
> understanding of the subject and does not include many details:
>
> *Her
> book on the history of cars in America was extremely superficial.*
>
> A person who is described as superficial does not want to think
> seriously about anything, even important matters.
> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/superficial)

---

> When one meets American children at hotels or on steamboats, one is
> inclined to form rather an unfavourable opinion of them. ...
>
> All this is quite a **superficial opinion**, the idea that one forms
> of American children at first sight. Look more deeply into their
> natures, associate with one or two of them for a few days; and you
> will receive a very different impression. [Mortimer Menpes; *World's
> Children*, p.50](https://www.google.com/books/edition/World_s_Children/VBQ9AAAAYAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=superficial%20opinion&pg=PA50-IA7&printsec=frontcover) (1903)

> Compassion can also be misguided, grounded in **superficial
> understanding**  of a situation. Compassion is not necessarily wise or
> appropriate.  [Lawrence Blum; *The Morality of Care*, p.182](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Moral_Perception_and_Particularity/Vrw5nh3v5nQC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=superficial%20understanding&pg=PA182&printsec=frontcover) (1994)

Answer (score 0):

**Misbegotten**; badly conceived or planned.

Example sentence: the misbegotten flanking manoeuvre left the whole vanguard in disarray.

Charles blurted out some misbegotten words which got him into great trouble.

Comment: I think that describes when you contemplate something but get it wrong, rather than not contemplating it at all.

Comment: Yes true actually you are correct.